# Accessing JSP session from servlet

Tags: jsp, taglib

im trying to establish and access a session from my servlet, but I can't get it working.

All tutorials just call request.getSession(true); for the session object, but I get "request can not be resolved".

I purely have to work with taglibs, no logic in the jsp page.

How can I access session data?
Thanks!

```
package controller;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;

public class Initialize extends BodyTagSupport
{
    public int doEndTag() throws JspTagException
    {
        try
        {
            // Implementation
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            out.println(session.getId());
            return SKIP_BODY;
        }
        catch(IOException error)
        {
            throw new JspTagException(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, i figured it out.
I had to use HttpSession session = pageContext.getSession();
And the page directive should have contained session="true".

Comment: the page directive shouldn't need the session="true" directive as thats the default behaviour. Unless you explicitly specify session="false" every jsp page will create a session for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right example for session data access from a taglib would have been:

```
package controller;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;

public class Initialize extends BodyTagSupport
{
    public int doEndTag() throws JspTagException
    {
        try
        {
            // Implementation
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            HttpSession session = pageContext.getSession(true);
            out.println(session.getId());
            return SKIP_BODY;
        }
        catch(IOException error)
        {
            throw new JspTagException(error);
        }
    }
}
```